# how to return the value from effect [NGRX] to component?

Tags: angular5, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

**in component.ts**

this.token$ = this.store.dispatch(new GetToken());

**in auth.effect.ts**

@Effect() getToken: Observable = this.actions.ofType(authActions.GET_TOKEN).switchMap(() => this.authService.getToken());

*Notice* this.authService.getToken() returns the token

*Error* Effect "AuthEffects.getToken" dispatched an invalid action

Answer (score 2):

Effect should have no direct relation to components. It is a side effect listening to your store and triggers a call to server when `GET_TOKEN` action is dispatched, then depending on the response, it should either dispatch an `GET_TOKEN_FAIL` or `GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS` with the newly received token as payload:

```
@Effect()
  refresh$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.GET_TOKEN),
    map((action: RefreshToken) => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((refresh_token: string) =>
      this.authService
        .refresh(refresh_token)
        .pipe(
          map(grant => new AccessTokenSuccess(grant)), // <- new token here
          catchError(error => of(new AccesTokenFail(error)))
        )
    )
  );
```

Then your reducers should update the store when `GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS` is dispatched to save the newly received one from the action's payload.

Your component just need to be listening to some selector mapping to that token in the store so he can know about the new value as soon as the store is updated by your reducers.

Comment: const defaultAuth: Auth = {
  user: null,
  pending: false,
  authenticated: false,
  error: null
};
Do you mean save token in this store?
and What's pipe Does?

Comment: Yes exactly. That is where you need to store it. In my code I use grant because there is also an expiration date info which I store with the token like: `const defaultAuth: Auth = { user: null, grant: {}, pending: false, authenticated: false, error: null }` where the grant will be filled by reducer later to look like `grant: {token:..., expiresAt:...}`

Comment: the `pipe` is optional. you don't have to use it but it is recommended to use lettable rxjs operators and have small bundles. you can read more about it [here](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44).